# Path inside svg is not rotating correctly

Tags: svg, rotation, transform

I want to make a simple effect with an svg path rotating inside another path. The code is as simple as:

```
    #lens {
animation: roll 2s infinite;

    }
    @keyframes roll {
        0% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
        100% {transform: rotate(360deg);}
    }
```

The idea is to make an eye rotating about axis, but instead of this it keeps rotating around whole svg. It's difficult to explain but you will understand the problem once you take a look on this jsfiddle template: https://jsfiddle.net/faster223/6d45ck42/

The eye is supposed to stay fixed on one place while rotating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `transform-origin: 50% 50%;` to #lens so it looks like this:

```
#lens {
    animation: roll 2s infinite;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
@keyframes roll {
    0% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    100% {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Let me add this for someone facing issue with SVG path rotation. you would need to have the below styles.

```
#lens {
  animation: roll 2s infinite;
  transform-origin: center;
  transform-box: fill-box;
}
@keyframes roll {
  0% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
  100% {transform: rotate(360deg)}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same issue and only the missing piece was transform-box: fill-box; thanks to @Aqib Mapari answer the below code works for me

```css
 #lens {
    animation: roll 2s infinite;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform-box: fill-box;

}
@keyframes roll {
    0% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    100% {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
```